# Jquery plugin syntax explained?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Ive seen some plugin code in jQuery

one of them is to overload the addClass method in jQuery (example :  when you addClass - call myfunction ()).

```
(function(){

    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        // call your function
        // this gets called everytime you use the addClass method
        myfunction();

    }
})();
```

the thing which i dont understand :

Why did he create a closure ?

I could use a private members inside a normal func with the `var` and it still be visible to the local scope only.....so ?

can you explain that to me ?

what does he earn from that closure ?

*I would have understand that if he sent the `$` sign to the function ...but he didnt*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closure was added so that the variable `originalAddClassMethod` isn't defined in the global scope (or parent scope), and is private to the plugin.

You said:

> I could use a private members inside a normal func with the var and it still be visible to the local scope only.

This is exactly what was done here: The function is anonymous, but still "normal".

Comment: I think the main goal with that kind of syntax is to use the $ sign inside..(which he didnt)...no ?

Comment: @Royi - You are right, the `(function($){})(jQuery);` is very common in plugins, but here the code isn't using the `$` variable, so it isn't really needed.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That syntax is usually used for two reason; a) to ensure `$` points to jQuery, and b) to provide a scope where private variables can be defined. In this situation, as \@Kobi pointed out, the author is using a closure for (b); without defining the closure 1) other 3rd party code could overwrite our declaration of `originalAddClassMethod`, or we could overwrite theirs.

Comment: @Royi - Yes. In JavaScript, you need a function to change the closure - it doesn't make a difference if they are named functions or anonymous.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I'm not sure how you mean *the same*. It should be worth noting that a **closure** is the term used to describe how an outer scope is retained until an inner function ceases to exist. What you have here is an [immediately-invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/); which creates a closure.

Comment: @Matt I mean that he could have wrap all the inside code in a normal function and then to call it.... `function Do(){all the inside code..};   ... and then call it Do();`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: They're almost the same.. but you leave yourself in a catch-22 situation, as one of the reasons we're using a closure here is to prevent overwriting any global variables. By declaring a function and then executing it, you run the risk of overwriting any variable named `Do`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `var` outside of a function you still create a global variable (because that's the scope you are in). So you need to wrap all code in a function to get a new scope.

The fact that he did not use the function to ensure `$` points to `jQuery` but used `jQuery` all the time instead just means that he was somehow masochistic and wanted less-readable code. ;)